# Does not conform to UITableViewDataSource - Parse app

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm using a `UITableView` in a `ViewController` connected to `TodayViewController`. I want to use data from my Parse database to load into the TableView.

Here is my `TodayViewController` class:

```
import UIKit
class TodayViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var InfoTableView: UITableView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    InfoTableView!.delegate = self
    InfoTableView!.dataSource = self
    loadParseData()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func loadParseData() {

    let query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "News")
    query.orderByDescending("Headline")

}


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewCell") as! PFTableViewCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = PFTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "NewCell")
    }

    //Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell

    if let Headline = object?["Headline"] as? String {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = Headline
    }
    if let Subtitle = object?["SubtitleText"] as? String {
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = Subtitle
    }

    return cell
}
```

This error crops up:

[image]

How do I solve the problem? Is there any mistake in the overall structure? Do request for more information if required.

Comment: remove UITableViewDataSource ,    InfoTableView!.dataSource = self and try once

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are not confirm to protocol UITableViewDataSource because you don't have a required method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

So you need to inherit PFQueryTableViewController to use the methods you want

```
class TodayViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {
...
}
```

Comment: Hey, but my table doesn't completely fill my ViewController. I have inserted a UITableView in a ViewController, so I need a ViewController class, not a TableViewController class. There is no 'PFQueryTableView' so I have to use the UITableView datasource and delegate. Is there any other way I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have implemented all the delegate methods of tableview outside the main class, i mean there will be a open parenthesis { and the close parenthesis should be end of all the methods. try like this

```
import UIKit
class TodayViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var InfoTableView: UITableView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    InfoTableView!.delegate = self
    InfoTableView!.dataSource = self
    loadParseData()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func loadParseData() {

    let query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "News")
    query.orderByDescending("Headline")

}


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewCell") as! PFTableViewCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = PFTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "NewCell")
    }

    //Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell

    if let Headline = object?["Headline"] as? String {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = Headline
    }
    if let Subtitle = object?["SubtitleText"] as? String {
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = Subtitle
    }

    return cell


  }
}
```

Hope this will help.